# Intent returning null value onActivityResult

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, android-intent

HI

I have a MainActivity Class which extends DashboardActivity Class. In Main activity class there are top action bar which when click will go to AddReminderActivity class. The action of the top action bar is defined in Dashboard Activity Class as

```
private void createReminder() {
    // TODO: fill in implementation
    Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,AddReminderActivity.class);
    Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "create reminder called");       
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Start Activity called Result");       
}

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Activity Result" + resultCode);       
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "Activity Result" + resultCode);    
        Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "intent Result" + intent.getExtras());    
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch(requestCode){
        case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                String title = extras.getString(ReminderDBAdapter.KEY_REMINDER_TITLE);
                String content = extras.getString(ReminderDBAdapter.KEY_REMINDER_CONTENT);
                mDbHelper.createReminder(title, content);
                mDbHelper.close();
              }
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ListReminder.class));
            break;

        }
        // TODO: fill in rest of method

    }
```

On the AddReminderActivityClass I have called

```
btnSubmitReminder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString(ReminderDBAdapter.KEY_REMINDER_TITLE, mReminderTitle.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString(ReminderDBAdapter.KEY_REMINDER_CONTENT, mReminderContent.getText().toString());
            if(mRowId != null){
                bundle.putLong(ReminderDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
            }
            System.out.println(mReminderTitle.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mReminderTitle.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            //setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
            if (getParent() == null) {
                  setResult(DashboardActivity.RESULT_OK, mIntent);
            } else {
                getParent().setResult(DashboardActivity.RESULT_OK, mIntent);
            }

            Log.i("in OnActivityResult", "set result" +RESULT_OK);       
            finish();

        }
    });
```

But when returning back to OnActivityResult the intent returns null and following exception occurs. I cannot recognize what the problem is

> ```
> 05-16 17:25:09.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): FATAL
> ```
>
> EXCEPTION: main     05-16
>   17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure
>   delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,
>   request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.babz.android.businessReminder/com.babz.android.businessReminder.MainActivity}:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   String resource ID #0xffffffff 05-16
>   17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) 05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) 05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   String resource ID #0xffffffff 05-16
>   17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   com.babz.android.businessReminder.DashboardActivity.onActivityResult(DashboardActivity.java:68)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
>   05-16 17:25:09.686:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment the setResult method call.

Comment: The setResult method has been called in the conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i can tell you get the exception when you try to get a value with a key that doesn't exist in the bundle, so in your case probably one of these:

```
String title = extras.getString(ReminderDBAdapter.KEY_REMINDER_TITLE);
String content = extras.getString(ReminderDBAdapter.KEY_REMINDER_CONTENT);
```

You can ask the bundle if the key exists by calling [containsKey(String key)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#containsKey%28java.lang.String%29) on the bundle, so i suggest you use that to find out if its the case or not.

Comment: Thanks. But i have debug and the value is coming in bundle.

Answer (score 1):

As Guru said, you setResult() method is not being called.  Thus the Intent is never being set.

I'm making a separate answer because there is a common problem that needs addressing: using the **wrong** setResult().

Make sure you use setResult(resultCode, intentData), NOT setResult(resultCode). I have to stress because many examples in many books use the latter, implying that the same intent that was sent into an Activity via startActivityForResult() will simply return that same Intent.  ALL Intents MUST be added directly, or you'll get NULL for the Intent in onActivityResult() every time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is in this line:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This causes the exception because the parameter `resultCode` is an `int` and in this case the `makeText()` method assumes that the value is a resource ID (ie: `R.string.something`). In this case, however, the value is -1 and that generates this:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff
```

You were actually hoping to call the `makeText()` method that takes a `String` instead. Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ResultCode: " + resultCode,
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```